# Drawing thick, doublesided arrows with texts between circles

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is the first time I'm using Latex to draw things, so this is all new to me.

I'm trying to draw the following

[image]

And I got the circles about right, but I have no idea how to draw these arrows:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (2cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(6,-8) circle (2cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(12,0) circle (2cm)}
\begin{scope}[ fill opacity=0.8]
    \fill[red] \firstcircle;
    \fill[green] \secondcircle;
    \fill[blue] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}

\draw \firstcircle node[] (c1) {Verwacht};
\draw \secondcircle node[] (c2) {Afspraak};
\draw \thirdcircle node[] (c3) {Geleverd};
\draw[<->] (c1) -- (c2);
\draw[<->] (c2) -- (c3);
\draw[<->] (c3) -- (c1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If anyone could help me with these arrows, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `arrows.meta` from `tikz` v3.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[fill=red,circle,minimum width=1cm] at (0,0) (c1) {Verwacht};
      \node[fill=blue,circle,minimum width=1cm] at (5,0) (c2) {Afspraak};
      \node[fill=green,circle,minimum width=1cm] at (2.5,-4) (c3) {Geleverd};
      \draw[draw=red!60!black,line width=12pt,{Latex[length=9mm]}-{Latex[length=9mm]}] (c1)  -- (c2) 
         node[midway,text=white,font=\footnotesize\bfseries]{tevreden};
      \draw[draw=red!60!black,line width=12pt,{Latex[length=9mm]}-{Latex[length=9mm]}] (c2) -- (c3) 
         node[midway,text=white,font=\footnotesize\bfseries,sloped]{betrouwbaar};
\draw[draw=red!60!black,line width=12pt,{Latex[length=9mm]}-{Latex[length=9mm]}] (c3) -- (c1) 
         node[midway,text=white,font=\footnotesize\bfseries,sloped]{duidelijk};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `arrows.meta` (should work with `tikz` v2.1)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=red,circle,minimum width=1cm] at (0,0) (c1) {Verwacht};
    \node[fill=blue,circle,minimum width=1cm] at (5,0) (c2) {Afspraak};
    \node[fill=green,circle,minimum width=1cm] at (2.5,-4) (c3) {Geleverd};
    \draw[draw=red!60!black,line width=10pt,stealth-stealth] (c1)  -- (c2) 
        node[midway,text=white,font=\footnotesize\bfseries]{tevreden};
    \draw[draw=red!60!black,line width=12pt,stealth-stealth] (c2) -- (c3)
        node[midway,text=white,font=\footnotesize\bfseries,sloped]{betrouwbaar};
    \draw[draw=red!60!black,line width=12pt,stealth-stealth] (c3) -- (c1)
        node[midway,text=white,font=\footnotesize\bfseries,sloped]{duidelijk};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, it all boils down to the selection/design of arrow tips. While `tikz` v3 offers numerous possibilities, those with v2.1 are limited. Choose an arrow type as per your taste.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use this code inside my article or do I need to put it in a separate file and use \input?

Comment: @Aaron You have many possibilities.. 1. Use `\includestandalone` (refer `standalone` manual). 2. Compile the above code to get a pdf and use `\includegraphics` 3. Copy the content from `\begin{tikzpicture}` ... `\end{tikzpicture}` and paste it in your document.

Comment: I keep getting errors about the \usetikzlibrary command, is there something special I need to do?

Comment: @Aaron with `arrows.meta`? You have to install `tikz` version 3. If you can't, use the second code with `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}`

Comment: Hmm, I did a full MikTex update and it's still not working. I can use the second example, but only if I leave out the import and then the arrow heads are black. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Aaron version 3 is not released yet with major tex distributions. you have to install it yourself from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/

Comment: I see, I'll use your other example, but it gives this: http://i.imgur.com/IW2DeC1.png

Comment: @Aaron Sorry, I can't test it (no v2.1). Please put `stealth-stealth` before `draw` like `\draw[stealth-stealth,draw=red!60!black,...]`. Does it work?